# resizing image so it fits into slide perfectly, still the issue is replacing css code with my image with for-loop

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm using owl carousel, and the default code I have has nice color background. but instead of the colored background, I want to use different images for each slide. I inserted an image as I have inserted the text, but the image is too big the whole thing collapses. Can you please help me with this one?
Here;s the carousel code

```
<div class="wrapper-with-margin">
<div id="owl-demo" class="owl-carousel">
{% for import in mustSee %}
     <div class="owl" style="white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis; font-size:12px;">{{import.title}}
    <img src="{{import.get_image_url}}" /></div>

{% endfor %}
</div>
</div>
```

The text gets displayed but the problem is the image, the image needs to be the background of the div tag. But thing is I'm using for loop to display different images for each slide, I can't directly change background like I would do in css. 
And In css,

```
#owl-demo .owl-item > div{
  background : #42bdc2;
  text-align: center;
  padding:50px 0px;
  margin:3px;
  color: white;
  font-size:32px;
  border:1px white;
}
```

Instead of

```
 background : #42bdc2;
```

I want this to be `<img src="{{import.get_image_url}}" />` of course, because I'm using for loop, I need to consider that too as well. how do I replace colored background with this image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could possibly use inline `css` to change the `background-image` property.

`<div style="background-image: url('{{import.get_image_url}}')">`

Make sure to set your [background](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background.asp) properties as well. Something like this, but taking into account **your** elements and image dimensions:

```
div {
  background: transparent url('fallback.jpg') no-repeat scroll center center / cover;
}
```

**UPDATED** to reflect your specific elements.

In your css doc you will want your `background` rules and your **fallback** image (I am assuming `.owl` is your class name):

```
.owl {
    background: #42bdc2 url('path/tp/fallback.jpg') no-repeat scroll center center / cover;
    text-align: center;
    padding:50px 0px;
    margin:3px;
    color: white;
    font-size:32px;
    border:1px white;
}
```

Now, for your inline styling (**note:** you don't want to use `<img src="">` for a css rule you just want to updated [`background-image`](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-image.asp) as you normally would):

```
<div class="owl" style="white-space: nowrap; overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis; font-size:12px; background-image: url('{{import.get_image_url}}')"></div>
```

Note the syntax - `background-image: url("url-goes-here");`; you'd obviously replace `url-goes-here` with `{{import.get_image_url}}` as shown in the example.

Comment: actually that's really good idea hmm not sure how I can do it tho, <div class="owl" style="white-space: nowrap;
 overflow: hidden;
 text-overflow: ellipsis; font-size:12px; background-image:<img src="{{import.get_image_url}}">??

Comment: @mikebraa I've updated my answer to show specific examples in regards to your code

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your question right, this is you wanna do in short:

> Use img-src as div's bg

You can do it easily using jquery

```
$(".your-div").each(function(){
  var imgSrc = $(this).find(".your-img-tag").attr("src");
  $(this).css("background","url('"+imgSrc+"')");
});
```

And if you dont want to show-up your image in img tag, you can either hide it or to have a clean code do put that img-url into `data-src` attr of your div and use the following code

```
$(".your-div").each(function(){
  $(this).css("background","url('"+$(this).attr("data-src")+"')");
});
```

Comment: however, looking at your question's title, there are many ways to achieve what you want. Some prefer the [centerCrop](http://jonathannicol.com/blog/2014/06/16/centre-crop-thumbnails-with-css/) way on the img tag itself rather than assigning that as div bg

Comment: oh shoot, I'm really bad at jquery...I kinda understand your code but not perfectly.  I'm trying to replace background : #42bdc2; with <img src="{{import.get_image_url}}" />

Comment: yep, this is what you want then. What i do is, take the img-url and assign it as div bg using jquery

Comment: so I need to replace your-img-tag with  <img src="{{import.get_image_url}}" /> ??

Comment: Yep, thats correct, you need to make jquery select/locate your img tag within the div. thats done by adding a class name to your img tag.

Comment: hmm, not sure how to do it I tried it like this; http://dpaste.com/3SXSXDV but won't work can you please help me